# Is it a problem if my sink drain fittings aren't quite straight?

Tags: plumbing, drain, kitchen-sink

I had new kitchen counters and a deeper sink installed, which made re-connecting my garbage disposal a bit of a challenge.  The drain is also further to the side, so I could no longer connect straight down to the existing plumbing, and since the sink is also lower and closer down to the existing plumbing, I ended up having to cut the disposal arm shorter and install a flexible drain pipe to make the connection (first picture).  However, this results in both drains (the one at the disposal and the other one also) not quite sitting flush with the sink due to the slightly forced angles this has created (second picture).  I was generous with plumbers putty and the connection at the sink seems to be successfully sealed, but I'm wondering if it's a long-term concern or anything.  (It bothers me a little that it looks wonky, but I can live with it to be done with this project for now). Sure, I can hire a plumber, but I do enjoy doing this and learning ways to do it better.

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: this is asking for troubles and leaks

Comment: Ah, yes. "Why I prefer slip fit traps anywhere that's not under concrete," writ large. Go nuts gluing PVC parts together and the only way to fix it when it's wrong is a saw. Slip fits can be adjusted to make everything line up nicely.

Comment: that's awful ... there is no reason for that ... some union junctions on the vertical pipe would make it easier to adjust the position of each trap

Comment: Accordion pipe and exposed electrical cable shouldn't even pass inspection in most places.  The cable at least might be grandfathered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't look quite right and the flexible connector is, at least in my opinion, undesirable.

If it were possible to rotate the wye on the stack at the back of the cabinet, then extend the horizontal arm from there to the P-trap, that would enable you to position the trap inlet directly below the disposer elbow outlet. It looks like those fittings are PVC solvent-weld, though, so repositioning those may not be an easy task. It would give you the opportunity to fix the strainer basket drain too though.

Another possibility for the disposal is to replace the elbow-type tailpiece with a straight tailpiece (also may be called an "end outlet"). An elbow and another straight section could complete the connection from the elbow down to the P-trap. You could then rotate the disposal and the P-trap, and adjust the length of the straight tailpiece, so that everything aligns nicely.

Comment: aha!  i hadn't realized i could get a straight tailpiece, i think that might do the trick.  you are correct that the solvent-welds on the left make any adjustments on that side much more difficult.  thank you so much!